# Other tabs keeps loading when setTimeout is set in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a javascript variable which will store HTML content, so here's what I'm doing:

```
$('.printScreen').on('click touchstart', function() {

    var myWindow = window.open();
    myWindow.document.write(printContents);
    setTimeout(function() { myWindow.print(); myWindow.close(); }, 50);

});
```

Now when I use `setTimeout()` other tabs don't work. When I do any action on other tabs it will just show a loading icon, and if I don't use `setTimeout()` it will just print a blank page.

Any Solution Appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the myWindow.print() fn as well?

Comment: @MarnixHarderwijk, see [`window.print`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print).

Comment: Does the print dialog open?

Comment: yes the dialog open

Comment: myWindow = window.open its just new tab page object